# Which is easier, yolo or tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, yolo

I want to use Raspberry Pi to recognize objects. To count the number of people. Which one should I use, yolo or tensorflow?

I don't know because I haven't done it yet, but it was hard doing YOLO right now. Would TensorFlow be easier?

Answer (score 1):

YOLO requires fewer computational resources compared to some TensorFlow models, which can be beneficial for Raspberry Pi applications.

And YOLO  is also best for real time object detection as compared to tensorflow.

The learning curve of YOLO may be more but it is worth it in the end

Comment: I also recommend YOLO, especially for devices such as RPI.  Make sure you use the right one:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#which_repos_to_use_and_avoid